# Use a local repository in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

When including external repositories in your Phoenix Framework project, it is possible to pass a Github option:

```
 {:example, "~> 0.9.9", github: "somewhere/example"}
```

Is there an option to include a local repository, similar to the Rails convention in the Gemfile?

```
 gem 'somewhere', '0.0.2', :path => 'some/local/directory'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter is just that, "path".

```
{:example, "~> 0.9.9", path: "some/local/directory"}
```

More of a Mix.Project question than a Phoenix question. See [the `mix deps` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely related to mix and as Don suggests you can find the documentation for that here:

https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html

However, make sure you dig deeper on the command line by typing `mix help deps` as the link provided does not give an example of how to refer to a local dependency.

Its not until you view the command line help that you will see a relevant example.